# Passing commandline argument to qml

Tags: linux, qt, shell, qml, command-line-arguments

I want to call a qml-script from linux shell and pass a text as parameter, like

```
./message.qml "hello this is a message"
```

or

```
/usr/bin/qt5/qml ./message.qml "hello this is a message"
```

The qml script should display that text.

The example qml script below works, but the text which is displayed ("hello") is static, of course. Is it possible to query command line arguments in the qml?

```
#!/usr/bin/qt5/qml

import QtQuick 2.2


Rectangle {
    width: 1024
    height: 600
    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Hello" // here I want to have a text which is set in the call
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            Qt.quit()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can access the command line arguments using [`Qt.application.arguments`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#application-prop), for example in my case if I execute:

```
/usr/bin/qml message.qml "hello this is a message"
```

```
#!/usr/bin/qt5/qml

import QtQuick 2.2


Rectangle {
    width: 1024
    height: 600
    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: Qt.application.arguments[2] // here I want to have a text which is set in the call
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            Qt.quit()
        }
    }
}
```

The index in `Qt.application.arguments[index]` may vary depending on how you invoke the execution of the qml.

Comment: This will throw an error/waring by `qml`, that it can not load the file *hello this is a message* as *no such file*.  In order to ignore subsequent commands you need `qml test.qml -- Hello` or `./test.qml -- Hello`.  So, argument number 3 must be used if you care about this error.  It would be nice if you could use `qml object.property=value test.qml` to alter behavior.  `Qt.application.arguments` can be used instead.